# laravel controller is not instantiable

Tags: php, exception, laravel, controller, instantiation

Im calling my controller in routes.php:

```
Route::get('request', 'Controller@request');
```

In my controller is the method request:

```
class Controller extends BaseController {

   public function request()
   {
        $number1 = int rand ( 10, 20 );
        $number2 = int rand ( 0, 10 );
        return View::make('request', array($number1, $number2));
   }
}
```

Problem is, that im getting error:

```
exception 'Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Controller] is not instantiable.'
```

I was browsing internet in order to find solution. A lot of simmilar errors are related to interfaces and I couldn't find anything useful. I renamed my controller once, what caused some error, but I repaired it with "composer dump-autoload" command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the controller class from:

```
class Controller extends BaseController {
```

To:

```
class ControllerController extends BaseController {
```

Why do this? Because `Controller` class already exists in Laravel (`BaseController` extends from `Controller`), so you probably want to name this to something else.

Also make sure the file is saved as `ControllerController.php` in the `controllers` dir.

Also your route should look like this:

```
Route::get('request', 'ControllerController@request');
```

I've tested this quickly on my local dev machine and it works.

Comment: `Why? because laravel requires your name all your controller classes with the suffix "Controller"`.... __wrong__ you can use any name (_foo_, _bar_).... suffix isn't needed. only need is, it has to extend from _BaseController_

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware. I've updated my answer. Still fairly new to Laravel and learning :)

Comment: laravel is too awesome! have fun!

Comment: I whole heartily agree! has been a blast working with Laravel so far.

Comment: also use namespace (if applicable).... it brings another dimension to the application.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem:

```
Target [App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Booking\BookingController] is not instantiable.
```

And the problem was that I had declared my constructor as private.

Code for reference:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Booking;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BookingController extends Controller
{
    private function __construct() {
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Removing the constructor or making it public resolved my error. Haven't tried actually making it work as private since I'm not that familiar with the whole single instance class (singleton) paradigm or if Laravel supports it (will have to read up on that).

Haven't found this specific situation elsewhere so hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

check `config/app.php` in *alias* section:

```
'Controller'        => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
```

the *controller* class already exists. if you want it, you have to namespace it.

e.g.

```
<?php namespace foo;

class controller extends \BaseController {

public function bar(){}

}
```

in routes:

```
Route::get('bar',['as'=>'foo.bar', 'uses' => '\foo\controller@bar']);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did and worked for me is this:

Under **app/Http/Controllers** use the classes

**Controlles.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

**YourController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function request() {
        $number1 = int rand ( 10, 20 );
        $number2 = int rand ( 0, 10 );
        return View::make('request', array($number1, $number2));
    }
}
```

the call in routes.php:

```
Route::get('request', 'YourController@request');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case of Google searches; Make sure

```php
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

is uncommented in your `RouteServiceProvider`. Laravel uses that field to assume what namespace your Controllers are located in, but without it, you have to be explicit about that in your Route definitions.